# How to use Report action in OSB proxy service to record retry attempts

Tags: proxy, osb

I want to record the retry attempts of a proxy service in OSB using report action.

I have created a JMS transport proxy service which would pick messages from an IN_QUEUE and routes the message to a business service which would push the message to an OUT_QUEUE and reports the status (success or failure).

However if there is an error while processing, the proxy service should retry for 5 times before getting failed. To acheive this, I have configured the routing options and gave the retry count as 5 and it works good.

All I want now is to record the retry attempts (using report action) of the proxy service. Please suggest me how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Logging the retry attempts of a business service is difficult, since it's handled out of the scope of the proxy. About the closest you can come is to set up a SLA alert to notify you when the bizref fails, but that doesn't trigger on every message - just if it detects errors during the aggregation interval.

Logging the retry attempts of the proxy is a lot easier, especially since it's a JMS proxy. Failed processing will put the message back on the queue (XA-enabled resources, you may want to enable Same Transaction For Response), and retries will increment a counter inside the JMS transport header, which the proxy can extract and decide whether to report on it or not.

Just remember that unless you set QoS to Best Effort on the publishes/reports, the publishes themselves will be rolled back if a failure happens, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: Thank you. I will try that.